# Como usar sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando passar o valor de um input de uma página para preencher outro input em outra página usando sessionStorage do HTML5, gostaria de saber pq este código não está funcionando.

```
//função que captura o valor de um input na página 1
    function valor(){
        var email = document.getElementById('email');
        var emailValor = email.value;

        var teste = window.localStorage.setItem('valor', emailValor);
        console.log(emailValor);        
    }
    valor();

//função que mostra o valor em outro input na página 2
    function mostraValor(){
        var data = window.localeStorage.getItem('valor');
            document.getElementById('email').value = data;
            console.log(data);
    }   
    mostraValor();
```

Comment: o que está dando de errado?

Comment: As páginas estão em um mesmo domínio?

Comment: Sim, estão no mesmo domínio, não sei o que está dando errado, pq o console não mostra erro algum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tem um erro de escrita.
tenta trocar

```
var data = window.localeStorage.getItem('valor');
```

por

```
var data = window.localStorage.getItem('valor');
```

Comment: Verdade Felipe, não tinha me atentado para o erro, agora funcionou, mas, pq o valor não aparece na primeira vez que vou da página 1 para a página 2 e sim só quando dou voltar na página?

Comment: Leandro, se tu estiver carregando a página na primeira vez pode não ter nada no storage e por isso não exibe nada.
Montei um pequeno exemplo utilizando o teu código. http://exemplostorage-felipelovato99885.codeanyapp.com/index.html

Comment: Entendi, seria possível a pessoa acessar a área de login e preencher um input com email e clicar enviar e ir para outra página com um input de email já preenchido pela primeira vez com este localStorage?

Comment: Sim, você pode colocar o script que carrega os dados do storage no **window.onload** da página.

Comment: tentei colocar assim window.onload = function(){mostraValor();}, mas não deu certo, tbm tentei por na tag body: onload=mostraValor(); mas ntbm não funcionou.

Comment: Deu certo aqui Felipe, haha, mas uma vez não estava dando certo por erro de escrita. Mas corrigi e funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Experimenta trocar no codigo  (tanto no setItem como o getItem):

```
window.localStorage
```

por

```
sessionStorage
```

Comment: sim já testei com localStorage, mas também não funcionou.

Comment: qual o erro que aparece na consola do browser?

Comment: Opa Rui já foi solucionado já, mas, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: localStorage e sessionStorage são coisas diferentes.

Answer (score -3):

Calculadora com sessionStorage

https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigo72/7wdzhsc8/